# Acquiring a global variable in a helper function with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope, global-variables

I'm making a function which will insert some simple HTML into my view. I've already done this several times without problems, but this time I'm going to use variables which are set in the Controller->extracted to the view.

Now, I obviously don't want to go away from my one-line shortcut: `<?php echo showStatusMessages(); ?>` by checking if variables are set, then send them as parameters etc. as this just kills the point of the function call altogether.

After some trying and failing I've ended up with a protected property which I'd like to use in my function. Any idea how I can find a way around this?

```
// Outputs success/error messages
function showStatusMessages() {

    $variables = array(
        'success',
        'error'
    );

    foreach ($variables as $variable) {
        // Cannot access protected property CI_Loader::$_ci_cached_vars
        if ($variable = $GLOBALS['CI']->load->_ci_cached_vars[$variable]) ${$variable} = $variable;
        break;
    }

    ob_start();

    // Success message set
    if (isset($success)) :
        echo '<div class="message_box success_color">'.$success.'</div>';
    endif;

    // Error message set
    if (isset($error)) :
        echo '<div class="message_box error_color">'.$error.'</div>';
    endif;

    $msg = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $msg;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't using a view?

```
<?php if (isset($success)) : ?>
    <div class="message_box success_color"><?php echo $success; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (isset($error)) : ?>
    <div class="message_box error_color"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And then calling this view using a one-liner, like this (assumes you named the view 'statusMessage':

```
<?php $this->load->view('statusMessage'); ?>
```

Doing it this way accomplishes what you're function is trying to; you can call it multiple times from a single line.

Comment: Weird that I didn't think of that elegant and simple solution. Back in the days I would have just used a simple `include()` statement, funnily enough using a framework complicates such simplistic thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Agree that it's not the preferred method however assigning a `$GLOBAL` will work just fine, and be accessible below the function runs in hierarchy. You will run into troubles attempting to assign it to the `$GLOBALS['ci']`.

In your helper:

```
function saveSomething($id){
    $GLOBAL['savedVars'][] = $id;
}
```

And in your view after your helper has been called:

```
var_dump($GLOBAL['savedVars']);
```